# nbgitpuller + jupyterhub = 404

Tags: docker, jupyterhub

I'm trying to get nbgitpuller to work in a jupyterhub environment.

The jupyterhub is working fine - I'm using thie repo: https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub-deploy-docker

I've installed nbgitpuller through the Docker bash, globally on host system and through the jupyerhub console. However, everytime I want to open a link I get the 404 error.

Any debugging help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you found any way to get it to work?
I also installed nbgitpuller in multiple ways, but only get 404

Comment: Not yet unfortunately :(

Comment: Same issue. Have you found any workaround?

Comment: Nope, meanwhile I have given up. Sorry.

Comment: same here jupyterhub on docker nginx reverse proxy all works well no nbgitpull though